# How to get the bounding rectangle after rotate at a its conner from P1 to P1'?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics

Please following the below image:

[image: Illustration Image]

I want to transform a Rectangle with anchor point is center of its from P1 to P1' point.

I want to compute the bounding rectangle after rotate.

I use a solution is get new 4points: P1 => P1' and P2 => P2' etc...
But problems is: the rectangle ( I expect to get) is larger.
Please tell me a way to get it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you know how to calculate the rotation itself? The bounding box itself is trivially calculated once you know P1' etc

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Problem is, I have computed like the first below answer of Andrey, but I get a bounding rect is larger. I don't know why? Maybe, I will update one more image for details.

Comment: Did you try my solution for calculating the new vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
left = min (Pi'.X for 1<=i<=4)
bottom = min (Pi'.Y for 1<=i<=4)
right = max (Pi'.X for 1<=i<=4)
top = max (Pi'.Y for 1<=i<=4)
width = top - bottom
height = right - left
bounding_rectangle = [left, bottom, width, height]
```

Update:

To rotate point `p` around `center` by `angle` radians:

```
v.x = p.x - center.x
v.y = p.y - center.y
newp = center.x + cos(angle) * v.x - sin(angle) * v.y, center.y + sin(angle) * v.x + cos(angle) * v.y
```

Applying this to each Pi you get Pi'

Comment: Could you tell me exactly how I get Pi'? And how is rotate angle? Because, I am coding a feature to rotate using mouse. When I click at conner and move mouse to P'. I need to paint a new rectangle and bounding of it?

Comment: Thank so much for your answer. I have done the same to you...
It's really good a solution. Maybe, the issues is from calculate with floating number. I will check again then to tell you again.

Comment: I don't think your calculation of newp is correct. Note that the rotation is around the center of the rectangle. Your solution would be correct for rotation around the center of an edge.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing this out! my mistake, i corrected signes

Comment: `width` and `height` are switched in your solution. it should read: `width = right-left` and `height = top-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

```
double halfDiagonal = sqrt((center.x - P1.x)*(center.x - P1.x) + (center.y - P1.y)*(center.y - P1.y));
double newAngle = rotationAngle + atan2(P1.y - center.y, P1.x - center.x);
newP1.x = center.x + halfDiagonal * cos(newangle);
```

Remaining coordinates and calculation of min/max is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I know what did you want to tell me.